# WordPres - How to add tax_query only to a custom post type without breaking any other query

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin which search result is showing using WordPress `tax_query` and it's post type is **pro_job**.

Now, I want to add new `tax_query` before the page is load. So, I have added following code:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );
function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    $job_location = isset( $_REQUEST['job_location'] ) ? $_REQUEST['job_location'] : '';
    if( !empty($job_location)){
        $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'job_location',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $job_location,
            )
        ));
    }

    return $query;
}
```

It's working fine but above this result, I used **ACF**:

```
$site_logo = get_field( 'header_logo', 'option' );
```

and I see that this `get_field()` is not getting any data. Showing error messages:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'sizes' in ......

If remove the `filter` then `get_Field()` is working fine.

Now, How can I set new `tax_query` to only `pro_job` post type with the same condition as I did above? Also, it's should **not** break any other query?

Comment: Hi.  In this `$site_logo = get_field( 'header_logo', 'option' );` what is option? Also, what page are you working on, can you just put a new WP_Query on the page template for your output?

Comment: @HowardE If you used ACF then you know we need to get custom field value using 'get_field()' method. and I used a shortcode on the page to modify the shortcode query

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how 'option' is set, and how your pre_get_posts would cause 'option' to fail, or the field 'header_logo'    -- how is the search output sent to the page? does the plugin have custom templates or filters?

Comment: @HowardE Thanks for your comment. I just solve it by overriding the templates files into my theme folder.